# convert from EBCDIC to UTF8 using informatica powercenter

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm a newbie in Informatica Powercenter and i'm trying to have my first step in this technology.

My first practice is to convert EDCDIC to UTF-8 using powercenter.

1. Is this possible to do that ?
2. If possible, then how can I do that ?. (I have referred to [this](https://community.informatica.com/thread/32591?db=5), but It doesn't help)
3. Is there anything that i need to pay attention to when doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do that. You have to just set the codepages properly in source and target definition.

Go to the advanced properties of your source definition and set the codepage to one of the EBCDIC codepages as appropriate for you.

Similarly in target definition set the codepage to UTF-8.

Also, the Informatica integration service should be configured in Unicode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is there any tuts or website where I can find out more ?

Comment: I tried to set codepage to target definition and source definition but there isn't any codepage that appropriate with my case. Any idea, please !

Comment: For example, I have a flat SAM file, which's encoding is ECBDIC, I want to create a transformation to convert it to utf-8 encoding file. I tried some code page such as CP037,CP420, IBM500,... But there are still some character can not be converted.As my searching, EBCDIC and utf-8 conversation is not supported. That why they create utf-ebcdic. But I want to make sure that is there anyway to convert ebcdic to utf-8 directly ?